# Why keyboard shortcut "ctrl + left" doesn't work?

Tags: macos, keyboard, mission-control, shortcut

I'm used to switch between my desktop spaces using <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + arrows. But <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> doesn't work while <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd> works fine.

Here is my settings:

[image: System Preferences > Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts > Mission Control]

Comment: OS version: 10.10.4 (14E46)

MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Early 2013)

Comment: did you try to click on it a reassign it ! or try using the "cmd" instead of "ctrl". A Question, did you reassign the cmd and ctrl  keys, since it is normally the "cmd" not the ctrl.

Comment: @Buscar웃SD after reassign it still doesn't work, but after rebooting it works fine. Thanks you!

Comment: Sorry, forgot to say you need to reboot :)

Comment: I always set these to ^⌘← and ^⌘→ so that they work the same as on my Linux installation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this problem:

1. Change keys for shortcut to <kbd>⌘CMD</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> (or anything else). But it won't work after that yet.
2. Reboot your mac.
3. <kbd>⌘CMD</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd> now is working.
4. Change keys to <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd>.

Comment: How do I add CTRL + LEFT arrow key in addition to the default CMD keys ? I don't want to replace.